# how long is 24bytes after base64url encoding

Tags: base64

I need to validate a base64url encoded string.  The requirement is given as

**random 24 bytes base64url encoded**

After converting this to base64url how long will the length be? I'm struggling to do the conversion and find the final length after converting 24bytes to base64url.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is very trivial to calculate, not to mention easy to check by testing in any programming language of your choice or even using various free websites that perform base64 conversions.

Comment: of course I tried to do something and read the theory around it, however I was not 100% on how the calculation works.  Plus when they say bytes its usually, 1s and 0s, whereas the examples given contain mostly alphanumeric characters.

Comment: *Bits* are 1s and 0s. [*Bytes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) are (in common usage) groups of 8 bits. In base 64, those bytes are alphanumeric characters plus 2 others (26 upper case, 26 lower case, 10 digits, `+`, and `/`). If you know that the input is 24 bytes (24 * 8 = 192 bits) and that the output is base 64 (64 possible characters = 6 bits of information encoded per character), then the math to figure out how many characters you need is extremely easy.

Comment: thanks for this, just a quick clarification why do you say 64 possible characters = 6 bits of information?

Comment: Because `64 = 2^6`. With 64 options for each byte, each byte can represent 2^6 possibilities, i.e., 6 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24 bytes will be encoded to 32 characters in Base64:

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx` ==> `YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4`

This can be seen in the following (courtesy of **[WebToolKit.info](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html)**):

```
console.log(Base64.encode('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx'));
console.log(Base64.decode('YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4'));
console.log("Length:", Base64.encode('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx').length); // 32
```

```js
/**
*
*  Base64 encode / decode
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/
var Base64 = {

// private property
_keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

// public method for encoding
encode : function (input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

    while (i < input.length) {

        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;
},

// public method for decoding
decode : function (input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    while (i < input.length) {

        enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

    }

    output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

    return output;

},

// private method for UTF-8 encoding
_utf8_encode : function (string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
    var utftext = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

        if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        }
        else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
        else {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }

    }

    return utftext;
},

// private method for UTF-8 decoding
_utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

    while ( i < utftext.length ) {

        c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

        if (c < 128) {
            string += String.fromCharCode(c);
            i++;
        }
        else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
            i += 2;
        }
        else {
            c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
            c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
            string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
            i += 3;
        }

    }

    return string;
}

}

console.log(Base64.encode('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx'));
console.log(Base64.decode('YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4'));
console.log("Length:", Base64.encode('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx').length);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks for this, how does the calculation work, I mean how does 24 bytes get converted to 32 characters?

Comment: Base64 encoding is not the same as Base64Url encoding.